# Sending commands from Android phone to Linux Desktop

Tags: android, linux, sms

Please point me to the right direction

I want to remotely send commands from my android phone to my linux desktop..

remotely as in via sms messages

So an android phone (android1) would be connected to my desktop via usb cable.

Another phone would then text my android phone i.e "shutdown"

so android1 would then read the message then shutdown the linux desktop that it is connected to.

I already have the message reading part.. I just want to know how to send commands from my android phone..

Thanks for your reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick-and-dirty solution, one possibility is to have the computer monitor logcat output, and react to certain lines that an app on the phone would output (System.out.print() will go to logcat).

There's probably a better solution out there, but I've not looked into using the USB cable for communication much.  I've been using our wifi network, since both the phone and computer are already on it.